# Usernames and passwords from database with php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to check usernames and passwords with my database. However each time i attemp to login with my "admin" accounts using the password "12341" it won't give me the results I want.

**login.php**

```
<div align="center" position="fixed" >  
     <form action="login_process.php" method="post">  
        <input name="username" type="text" value="" size="9"><br>  
        <input name="pass" type="password" value="" size="9"><br>  
        <input type="submit" value="Log in">  
     </form>  
</div>
```

**login_process.php**

```
require_once('db_conn.php');



if (!isset($_POST['username']) || !isset($_POST['pass'])) {  
    echo 'U moet een gebruikersnaam en wachtwoord invoeren!';  
    exit;  
}

$sql = "SELECT `username`,`password` \n"
. "FROM `tryusers` \n"
. "WHERE `username` = \'Admin\'\n"
. "AND `password` = \'12341\'";
$sql = "SELECT `username`,`password` FROM `tryusers` WHERE `username` = " . $_POST['username'] . " AND password = " . $_POST['pass'] . "";
$results = $conn->query($sql);
    var_dump('postuser',$_POST['username'],'<br>');
    var_dump('postpass',$_POST['pass'],'<br>');
if(!$results){
    echo 'no results';
} else {
    echo $results;
}
```

**db_conn.php**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "trybase";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Regards,
Sem

Comment: 1) used prepared statements against SQL injections. 2) Check the error messages after the queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make quotes arround the variables:

```
$sql = "SELECT `username`,`password` FROM `tryusers` WHERE `username` = '" . $_POST['username'] . "' AND password = '" . $_POST['pass'] . "'";
```

Or better use prepared statements.

Comment: Ugh. So simple, overlooked that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you forgotten ' when pasting data from the form.
Btw check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) because your code is dangerous.

Comment: I'm quite new to using databases, and I wasn't fully informed on the SQL injections thing. So I'll definitly put that in. Thanks/